# I have just started learning android studio using Kotlin, and I am getting this error in literally the first app/program I am trying to run

Tags: android, kotlin

So, as mentioned I've literally just started learning android studio, I am using the Flamingo version.
I am trying to make an app which has a text field which takes the name of user and just displays it like "Hello xyz" when the button is clicked.

[The code snapshot, see line 21 with the error message when I hover over it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crnIL.png)

this is the error I am getting when using the .text option with the textView. It just says variable expected. I've tried googling it, I've completely uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio three times and now I am coming to you guys for the solution, please help!

Tried everything, googling, installing Android Studio, nothing worked at all!

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val greetingTextView = findViewById<textView>(R.id.tv1)
        val inputField = findViewById<editText>(R.id.name)
        val submitButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        submitButton.setOnClickListener{
            val inputName = inputField.text.toString()
            val msg = "welcome $inputName"
            greetingTextView.text = msg
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using textView and editText, you should be using TextView and EditText (note the uppercase T and E). The correct code should be:

```
val greetingTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv1)
val inputField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.name)
```